# Kotlin fails to get the right enum instance

Tags: java, kotlin, enums, compiler-errors, type-inference

So we are using Vaadin. Vaadin comes with a `Key` interface. I copied it and deleted all entries except the `CONTROL` key (for demonstration purposes here, we don't copy the classes in our actual code):

```java
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface VaadinKey extends Serializable {

    VaadinKey CONTROL = VaadinKey.of("Control", "ControlLeft", "ControlRight");

    //...

    static VaadinKey of(String key, String... additionalKeys) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(key);
        if ("".equals(key)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'key' cannot be empty");
        }
        List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        keys.add(key);
        keys.addAll(Arrays.asList(additionalKeys));
        return () -> keys;
    }


    List<String> getKeys();


    default boolean matches(String key) {
        return getKeys().contains(key);
    }


    static boolean isModifier(com.vaadin.flow.component.Key key) {
        return Stream.of(VaadinKeyModifier.values())
            .anyMatch(k -> k.matches(key.getKeys().get(0)));
    }

}
```

The interface is implemented by a `KeyModifier` class, that I've also copied out and stripped down:

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public enum VaadinKeyModifier implements VaadinKey {

    /**
     * KeyModifier for "{@code Control}" key.
     */
    CONTROL(VaadinKey.CONTROL)

    //...
    ;

    private final VaadinKey key;

    VaadinKeyModifier(VaadinKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }


    @Override
    public List<String> getKeys() {
        return key.getKeys();
    }


    public static VaadinKeyModifier of(String key) {
        return Stream.of(values()).filter(k -> k.matches(key)).findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }
}
```

Now let's try to use it from Kotlin:

```kotlin
fun foo() {
    val ctrl: VaadinKeyModifier = VaadinKeyModifier.CONTROL
}
```

This will fail to compile because

> Type mismatch: inferred type is VaadinKey! but VaadinKeyModifier was expected

(And if I ctrl+click it in IntelliJ, it will also take me to the `VaadinKey` interface.)

I also tried

```kotlin
import com.[...].VaadinKeyModifier.CONTROL as CONTROL_MODIFIER

fun foo() {
    val ctrl: VaadinKeyModifier = CONTROL_MODIFIER
}
```

With the same result.

Now interestingly, the direct use of `VaadinKeyModifier.CONTROL` will not register any usage of `VaadinKeyModifier::CONTROL`, whereas the `import` variant registers one usage in the import (which however does not prevent the compilation error).

What gives?

Why does this happen?

And how do I get this to work?

Comment: hey sorry for asking but what exactly `CONTROL(VaadinKey.CONTROL);` should do in  VaadinKeyModifier ? by the way of look when you call  `VaadinKeyModifier.CONTROL`  it should call its parent's CONTROL property because  `CONTROL(VaadinKey.CONTROL);`   is actually doing nothing

Comment: @ErfanDP well, it should define a `VaadinKeyModifier` enum constant called `CONTROL` that takes `VaadinKey.CONTROL` as its constructor parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of your enum instance (`CONTROL`) clashes with its self-titled field inherited from the interface.

In Java this ambiguity resolves in favor of enum instance, in Kotlin (during Java interop) for some reason it resolves in favor of field. However if `VaadinKeyModifier` class was defined in Kotlin, it would have been resolved in favor of enum:

```kotlin
enum class VaadinKeyModifierKT(private val key: VaadinKey) : VaadinKey {
    CONTROL(VaadinKey.CONTROL);
}

val ctrl: VaadinKeyModifierKT = VaadinKeyModifierKT.CONTROL //Would be compiled
```

If changing given code to avoid this ambiguity (for instance, via renaming fields/enums or separating interface and these fields) is not an option, then you can access instances of `VaadinKeyModifier` via its name:

```kotlin
val ctrl = enumValueOf<VaadinKeyModifier>("CONTROL")
```

As a less error-prone option, I'd suggest creating auxilary enum, duplicating values of `VaadinKeyModifier`, with converter to `VaadinKeyModifier` type:

```kotlin
enum class Modifier {
    SHIFT,
    CONTROL,
    ALT,
    ALT_GRAPH,
    META;

    fun toVaadinKeyModifier() : VaadinKeyModifier = enumValueOf(name)
}

//Usage:
val ctrl: VaadinKeyModifier = Modifier.CONTROL.toVaadinKeyModifier()
```

Comment: Care to elaborate? I did mention these two classes are part of the Vaadin framework, so I'm not exactly sure how I'm supposed to rename the enums or separate the interfaces. (Unless you mean we should copy the classes into our own code and ignore the ones provided by the framework, which we will not do for the simple fact that the framework would not accept our instances where it would expect theirs.)

Comment: Updated my answer with possible workaround

Comment: That's quite beautiful for a workaround. Thank you!